# A tedious tale with hidden meaning

Tags: word, rhyme, wordplay

I'd like to share with you a story about my yesterday. Perhaps you'll find it more exciting than I do.

---

*I found a free-range donkey

next to a free-range horse

and what I did with them, you ask?

I had them breed, of course!

They had one foal and left him

afraid and all alone

so I threw a pack upon his back

and kept him as my own*

*I wandered through the jungle

over buggy, muggy ground

when I felt something slipping --

oh, my pants were falling down!

I located some tangled vines

('twere thin and didn't bite)

and wrapped them well around my waist

to hold my pants up tight*

*Tonight I sleep quite soundly

as imps prance through my head

I think of dragons and gypsy wagons

as I lie still in my bed

I force myself to stay asleep

so the fantasies persist

but to my surprise, as I arise

the fantasies exist!*

*Each stanza holds a two-word phrase

all key to my solution

though in each case, you'll need to make

a rhyming substitution!

And once you've found the phrases

and you've located the rhymes

You'll find the answer, clear as mud

(a vapid waste of time)*

---

So, what's the hidden message in my story?

Comment: Impressive rhyming! Can I suggest that you add an extra syllable to "and located the rhymes"? Maybe "all"? Unless that would change the solution..

Comment: It wouldn't change the solution! I think it depends on how you read it - when I hear it in my head, it goes: "and ONCE you've FOUND the PHRA-ses / and LO-ca-TED the RHYMES", with a breath pause after each line, though if you read it "and lo-CA-ted ALL the RHYMES", you get a very similar effect.

Comment: Just to be clear, "Each stanza" refers to all four, or the three above? I have a guess as far as two word phrases go, but I don't see it in stanza four.

Comment: @Josh yeah the fourth is just directions, basically.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but I think that with the other 6 lines, its flow is wrong. "each STANza HOLDS a TWO-word PHRASE all KEY to MY solUTion // though IN each CASE you'll NEED to MAKE a RHYMing SUBstiTUtion // and ONCE you've FOUND the PHRAses —— and LOcatED the RHYMES // you'll FIND the ANSwer, CLEAR as MUD (a VAPid WASTE of TIME)." The other pairs of lines don't have that breath between them, so it feels unnatural (especially mid-sentence). Also, I think it's more natural to want to elongate the A than the E in "located".

Comment: @IanMacDonald I see what you mean! I added a 'you've' which should clear it up! Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Haha, I have to admit, these clues makes me think of Muggy Buggy Fun Run in Minocqua Park. :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*I found a free-range donkey

next to a free-range horse

and what I did with them, you ask?

I had them breed, of course!

They had one foal and left him

afraid and all alone

so I threw a pack upon his back

and kept him as my own*

> Sounds like you ended up with a **PET MULE**.

*I wandered through the jungle

over buggy, muggy ground

when I felt something slipping --

oh, my pants were falling down!

I located some tangled vines

('twere thin and didn't bite)

and wrapped them well around my waist

to hold my pants up tight*

> You improvised a **PLANT BELT**.

*Tonight I sleep quite soundly

as imps prance through my head

I think of dragons and gypsy wagons

as I lie still in my bed

I force myself to stay asleep

so the fantasies persist

but to my surprise, as I arise

the fantasies exist!*

> And woke up to some **REAL DREAMS**.

*Each stanza holds a two-word phrase

all key to my solution

though in each case, you'll need to make

a rhyming substitution!

And once you've found the phrases

and you've located the rhymes

You'll find the answer, clear as mud

(a vapid waste of time)*

> If we take all the words from the phrases above, "Pet mule plant belt real dreams," and instead substitute a rhyming word for each, we (of course) end up with the phrase, "Jet fuel can't melt steel beams."

Comment: Oh God, that phrase again!

Comment: Haha, wow... can't believe I missed that one!

Comment: Quite well done. :)

Comment: But mind control chemicals can.

Answer (score 0):

*Each stanza holds a two-word phrase

all key to my solution

though in each case, you'll need to make

a rhyming substitution!*

I think this means that in each stanza we need to

> replace one word by another, twice (getting two new words), in such a way as to make *all* the lines rhyme rather than just nearly all.

For the first stanza,

> 1) replace "donkey" by "ass" to (almost) rhyme with "ask", at least in some accents (not mine, but never mind)
> 2) I think the "foal" line should have a "hole" somewhere, so that it rhymes in the same way as "pack"/"back"
> So the first stanza gives ASSHOLE (!)

*[work in progress]*

Comment: Oh, my! No, that's not exactly what I had in mind... O_o